# Does Entity Framework Core HasAlternateKey remove index on FK?

Tags: .net, t-sql, orm, entity-framework-core

I have ASP.Net Core app which uses Entity Framework Core ORM and two entities in MS-SQL DB which have one-to-many relation - Company and Trigger. So company can have multiple triggers. They are mapped like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OnsiteCampaignTrigger>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Campaign)
                .WithMany(x => x.Triggers)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CampaignId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Each trigger has a type and I want to be able to create only one trigger of each type of one company. So I want to make combination of Type and CompanyId columns unique for Triggers table. I decided to use HasAlternateKey configuration in this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Trigger>()
                .HasAlternateKey(x => new { x.CampaignId, x.Type });
```

But in EF migration I got this:

```
migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Triggers_CampaignId",
                table: "Triggers");

migrationBuilder.AddUniqueConstraint(
                name: "AK_Triggers_CampaignId_Type",
                table: "Triggers",
                columns: new[] { "CampaignId", "Type" });
```

So it looks like it droped my index on CampaignId foreign key! Will this lead to performance degradation?

Comment: If you want an index on `x.CampaignId` you have to add it separately in the mapping by a data annotation or fluent mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique index that is built for `AK_Triggers_CampaignId_Type` would do everything that the index `IX_Triggers_CampaignId` would do (because all the key columns in `IX_Triggers_CampaignId` are included, in the same order, at the beginning of the key columns of `AK_Triggers_CampaignId_Type`), but with a slightly larger size. I'd say that the performance difference due to the slightly larger index size is negligible, so it's not worth it to waste space to have another index with almost the same data (because that would imply a small performance penalty for inserts/updates/deletes).